# Como faço para mostrar os resultados de um certo ano?

Tags: php, table

Eu tou tentanto fazer um código onde ele só mostre os resultados de um ano mas assim não aparece nada.

```
    <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','formulario');

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE data=2019");
    $r = mysqli_num_rows($res);

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

  $id=$r['id'];
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$r['id'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r['data'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>' .$r['escola'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r['nome'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r['processo'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$r['email'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
  echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a estrutura da tabela no banco de dados? Qual o valor de `$linhas`? Quais as últimas mensagens no arquivo de log do seu servidor?

Comment: ja modifiquei mas mesmo assim nao aparece nada, fica em branco

Comment: Sua tabela não possui uma coluna chamada `dataenvio`

Comment: sim ja mudei tmb mas fica igual

Comment: E, novamente, qual o valor de `$linhas` e quais as últimas mensagens de log do seu servidor?

Comment: eu ja mudei o valor $linhas para $r

Comment: Obs.: O tipo da coluna `data` é `datetimr`, o que indica que possui uma data e um horário. Você só está comparando o valor com um ano.

Comment: ent se mudar para data vai funcionar?

Comment: Recomendo você ler a documentação sobre os tipos antes e entender o que está fazendo do que sair testando alterações aleatórias.

Comment: e onde posso eu encontrar isso?

Comment: ja resolvi era adicionar like e o ano $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE dataenvio LIKE '%2018%'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar a função `YEAR` para pegar apenas o ano da data e compara com o valor desejado.

O problema está na condição do `sql`:

```
... WHERE data = 2019
```

O correto seria:

```
... WHERE YEAR(data) = 2019
```

Comment: eu pos assim  $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE dataenvio LIKE '%2018%'");

Comment: poder pode... mas acredito que a forma mais correta seja usando `YEAR`, não acho que `LIKE` seja indicado para trabalhar com o tipo `date`, embora funcione...